# Handle Invalidated Token Alert from Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

> P.S: Please help me vote up this question since it is really really
>   difficult to find the solution.

Below is my code to check if my facebook token is valid or not.

```
        var request: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil);

        request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                println("No Error")
            }
            else {
                PFFacebookUtils.unlinkUserInBackground(SLUser.currentUser()!);
                println("Error")
            }
        }
```

What is weird is that, IF the token is not valid (user has changed password or user has revoked the application permission) the app automatically shows an Alert like below.

[image: Error Dialog that Comes Up]

My question is:

1. How do I handle when user press OK or Cancel?
2. Is it possible to disable that Alert or Replace it?

Comment: I don't believe this comes from the SDK so there is probably no callback to  either handle the button clicked or to disable to alert. This seems like it could be related to the iOS system settings, can you check if your are logged into Facebook through the iOS settings?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I want to handle that error my own way instead of letting the fbsdk throw the default alert that it does.